# Angular not able to reach my own APIs [404 (Not Found)]

Tags: node.js, angular, api

I just started to learn something about APIs but after many tentatives I'm still not able to trigger mine.
[as you can see from this image this is the error i am having.] https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lvyww.png

This is the code that I wrote (I know , it's very simple.. but I'm just trying to learn something.. :)

**server.js**

```
const cors = require("cors");
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();
app.use(cors({origin:'*'}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/sendmail',(req,resp)=>{
    res.json({
      "statusCode" : 200,
      "statusMessage" : "Success!"
}
```

**http.services.ts**

```
constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

sendEmail(){
    this.http.post('/api/sendmail',{}).subscribe((response)=>{
      console.log(response);
    },(error)=>{
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

sendEmail method is bound to a button.

**proxy.config.json**

```
{
    "/api/*":{
        "target" : "http://localhost:4200",
        "secure" : false,
        "pathRewrite" : {
            "^/api" :""
        }
    }
}
```

**package.json**

```
"main": "server.js",
```

I also tried to run by using this command **ng serve --proxy-config  proxy.config.json**

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: let's just take your API alone. Are you able to reach it a result with a simple POST request to `http://localhost:4200/sendmail`, for instance using `curl` or a tool like PostMan ?

Comment: Are you providing the proxy.config.json in the angular.json config?

Comment: Hi everybody, thanks for the response.
I tried to trigger the url in postman but I'm getting the same error, I also tried to put the proxy.config.json file in angular.json below serve -> options by adding proxyConfig line

"serve": {"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
                "options": {
                 "browserTarget": "ClientWebsite:build",
                  "proxyConfig":"proxy.config.json"
}... Still the same

Comment: So is your api really at port 4200? Somehow I doubt it, 4200 should be angular front end if you haven't changed it.

Comment: Yes the port is 4200, the same for angular front end

Comment: So how do you think that angular knows where to search for the api? It will look into it's own folder structure, where assumingly it isn't? Usually we run backends on different ports/ip.

Comment: What I mean is... that currently Angular will look for a **route** `http://localhost:4200/sendmail` just like it would search for a homepage if you have one named `http://localhost:4200/home`